# How to Upload a File Inside a Modal using wicket

Tags: java, ajax, file-upload, wicket

I try to use a Wicket Modal Window to set the PropertyModel of an Entity. The problem is this Entity has a FIleUploadFields that i read non work nice with Ajax. I need to use AjaxSubmitLink inside the modal and i don't be able to get this work fine.

```
setMultiPart(true);

setMaxSize(Bytes.megabytes(100));

fileUpload = new FileUploadField("fileUpload");

fileUpload.setOutputMarkupId(true);
fileUpload.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
add(fileUpload);

save_btn = new AjaxLink("save_btn") {

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget art) {


                final FileUpload uploadedFile = fileUpload.getFileUpload();
                if (uploadedFile != null && uploadedFile.getSize() > 0) {
                    try {
                        if (GestioneDocumentiDcs.isTextDocument(uploadedFile)) {
                            String ext = GestioneDocumentiDcs.getTextExtension(uploadedFile.getContentType());

                            String nomeFile = "c_" + _corso.getId() + "_m_" + materialeCorso.getId() + ext;
                            byte[] b = ByteStreams.toByteArray(uploadedFile.getInputStream());
                            gd.salvaFile(b, gd.getPathCorso(_corso) + "/" + nomeFile);
                            materialeCorso.setPercorso(nomeFile);
                            materialeCorso.setDimensione(uploadedFile.getSize());
                            materialeCorso.setDataUpload(LocalDate.now());
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println("ERRORE: " + Utils.StampaStackError(e));
                    }
                }
```

this is my code inside the Modal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AjaxLink` does **not** submit the form, so nothing will be transferred to the server. You need either `AjaxButton` or `AjaxSubmitLink`.